# WordPress pagination disappear when switch language

Tags: wordpress, pagination, wpml

I'm using WPML to make my site be able to switch between two different languages(Eng/Chinese), and on my posts page usually there are auto pagination. Now the pagination is working well under English but not working under Chinese.

Please help to find how can i solve this problem.

Comment: I am guessing that the posts have no chinese translation, hence no pagination.